# Localhost intercept not working for burp suite

Tags: firefox, burp-suite

I configured my Firefox proxy to send my php website traffic running on localhost to burp suite for intercept but its not intercepting anything. My Firefox and Burp Suite configurations [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjMm.jpg). I've tried using different port other than 8080, went to `about:config` and enable localhost hijacking but still it wont work. Days ago it was working fine but now its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the screenshots you provided, your Firefox is configured wrong. The bottom section states

> No proxy for:
>
> ```
> localhost, 127.0.0.1
> ```

This means that Firefox will ignore proxy settings for these addresses. Since you explicitly want to intercept traffic going to these addresses, remove them, and it will work.

Comment: My php site hosted using xampp Apache wont be able to load if i remove it.It says "The proxy server is refusing connections".I used the same settings before but it worked previosly
Edit: Looks like i configured the proxy wrong indeed,its now working.Thanks alot for the help

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the default port of Burp then, other than 8080. As far as I know, XAMPP uses 8080 for something.